# Custom price in case of selecting PayPal payment method

Tags: commerce

There is a site with goods on Drupal Commerce.

The client asked him to make special arrangements for visitors of the site, who pay for goods through PayPal. Because there're commissions of PayPal and the client does not want to loose money because of them, but wants when choosing Paypal as a method of payment the price to be increased by 4%.

How to make price variations depending on the choice of method or do I need to try to make it with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

There are 3 payment methods on the website:

1. Bank Transfer
2. Pay in Person
3. Paypal

What I did by now:

I created a TAX that adds to a price by 0.04%.

I created a rule:

Event
Calculating the sell price of a product

Conditions

Selected payment method comparison
Parameter: Order: [site:current-cart-order], Payment method: PayPal WPS

NOT Selected payment method comparison
Parameter: Order: [site:current-cart-order], Payment method: Bank Transfer

NOT Selected payment method comparison
Parameter: Order: [site:current-cart-order], Payment method: Pay in person

Actions

Apply a tax rate to a line item
Parameter: Line item: [commerce_line_item], Tax rate: PayPal tax
Provides variables: Applied tax (applied_tax)

In Checkout settings (admin/commerce/config/checkout) I moved admin/commerce/config/checkout

to the checkout pane.

But the commission is added to all products. No matter what payment method is chosen. Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What a greedy client. What other payment method is he currently using anyways? If he is not using paypal, he must be using someone else who also charges like paypal (payment gateways need to make a living). So why not increase all prices by 4% regardless of payment method?

Comment: Also think that site displays prices in add to cart form before choosing payment method, and it's not going to be nice to change prices after choosing payment method. I agree with No Sssweat (increase all prices by 4%). Then by rules you can make a discount in a LINE ITEM (not in price) depending on payment method.

Comment: Already solved this problem

Comment: Just needed to move Shopping cart contents to review
/admin/commerce/config/checkout